# Unable to Setup Edge browser through github actions

Tags: c#, github-actions, ui-automation, cicd, selenium-edgedriver

I have an Selenium Automation project locally. As per project requirement I have to run the selenium project into Linux host machine using github actions for that I was trying to install the Edge browser as the host doesn't contains any browser.

Here's the Actions Workflow Code I used.

```html
steps:
  - uses: browser-actions/setup-edge@v1
  - name: Print Edge version
    run: (Get-Item (Get-Command msedge).Source).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

And the Error I'm facing

```html
Run browser-actions/setup-edge@v1

Setup Edge stable
Attempting to download Edge stable...
Acquiring stable (115.0.1901.183) from https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-stable/microsoft-edge-stable_115.0.1901.183-1_amd64.deb
unable to get local issuer certificate
Waiting 13 seconds before trying again
unable to get local issuer certificate
Waiting 15 seconds before trying again
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```